# Iterating over list of structs

Tags: c++, list, struct, iterator

I'm creating a list of structs:

```
struct task{
    int task_id;
    bool is_done;
    char* buffer;
    int length;

} task;
list<task> taskList;
```

And trying to iterate over the tasks in order to check the is_done status:

```
    for (std::list<task>::const_iterator iterator = taskList.begin(), end = taskList.end(); iterator != end; ++iterator) {

        if(iterator->is_done) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 2;
        }
    }
```

Where am I wrong?
I get: Missing template argument before '->' token

Comment: Where you are wrong at what ?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @nosid: It is commonly called asterisk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iterator's `operator->` does the dereferencing already. So instead of

```
if(*iterator->is_done==true)
```

you need

```
if(iterator->is_done==true)
```

is equivalent to

```
if((*iterator).is_done==true)
```

which as a sidenote is equivalent to the easier to read

```
if((*iterator).is_done)
```

or

```
if(iterator->is_done)
```

. Even better, you could also use `std::any_of`:

```
#include <algorithm>

....

if (any_of(begin(taskList), end(taskList), 
    [](task const &t) { return t.is_done; }))
{
    return 1;
} else {
    return 2;
}
```

Informal note: There is no need to qualify `any_of`, `begin` and `end` with `std::`, because `taskList` is of type `std::list<?>`, and the C++-compiler will look up those functions in the `std`-namespace for you already.

Comment: This question wasn't tagged with [c++11] so why suggest the use of lambda functions?

Comment: @trojanfoe: Because it's the year 2013 now.

Comment: Yes, but C++11 still isn't commonly available, for example in Red Hat 6, HP/UX, AIX, Solaris?

Comment: @trojanfoe: But for what definition of "commonly"? And how is the point in time defined beyond which "The Current C++ Standard" refers to the current C++ standard? The smallest common denominator is the moment ISO has declared that C++ is C++11, which was in late 2011. Like I do expect [C++11] answers when asking [C++] questions, I expect the same from questioners. If they need an answer specific to their compiler, or specific to a _previous_ standard, they should use specific tags and/or mention that in the question.

Comment: Therefore: This question wasn't tagged [c++03], so why not suggest the use of lambda-functions and the any_of-algorithm as well as the new begin/end-functions?

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
if (iterator->is_done==true){
```

no need for `*` and `->`.

And not the question you asked but

```
if (iterator->is_done==true) {
```

is exactly the same as the easier to understand

```
if (iterator->is_done) {
```

Don't compare booleans to true and false, they already are true and false.

Comment: Unfortunately, in the english language, `no need for * and ->.` is ambiguous: Is it `no need for (* and ->)` or `(no need for *) and (no need for ->)`?

Comment: Thanks, now I"m using:
 for (std::list<task>::const_iterator iterator = taskList.begin(), end = taskList.end(); iterator != end; ++iterator) {
     if(iterator->is_done){
      return 1;
     }

     else{
      return 2;
     }

And I get:
MISSING template arguments before ')' token

Comment: Normally you would say "no need for *both* `*` *and* `->`" to remove the ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::find_if` instead:

```
#include <algorithm>

...

bool isDone(const task &task)
{
    return task.is_done;
}

...

return std::find_if(taskList.begin(), taskList.end(), isDone) == taskList.end() ? 2 : 1;
```

Comment: how about `any_of` instead?

Comment: @phresnel Is there any advantage to using that?

Comment: It's less verbose ("`== taskList.end`"), requires less knowledge of the standard library ("`== taskList.end`") and does return a yes/no-answer instead of a "fully fledged" iterator that you throw away right at the end of expression, which means the semantics are more clear. / For an example, see my answer.

Comment: One more argument: In theory, `any_of` could be implemented multithreaded/data-parallel, without a reduction step, whereas `find_if` is restricted to finding the _first_ match; i.e. if implemented multithreaded or data-parallel, there's a need for a reduction step. The looser the restrictions, the more performant such function can be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Note change to task struct and referencing iterator.  (I changed name of iterator - to be more concise - but not actually required).  I just think looks less confusing.

```
#include <list>

using namespace std;

struct task{
    int task_id;
    bool is_done;
    char* buffer;
    int length;

};


int main() {

    std::list<task> taskList;
    task task1;
    task1.buffer = "qwerty";
    task1.is_done = true;
    task1.length = 6;
    task1.task_id = 1;
    taskList.push_back(task1);


    for (std::list<task>::const_iterator it = taskList.begin(), end = taskList.end(); 
       it != end; ++it) {
        if((*it).is_done==true)
            return 1;
        else
            return 2;
    }

    return 0;
}
```